# Microsoft Translation API Authentication Failure

Tags: azure, microsoft-translator

We currently have both a TEST and DEV environment of our application set to connect to Microsoft Translator. For our test environment, everything connects fine. For our DEV environment, authentication is failing and we do not know why. Both machines appear to have the same configuration. We are testing both with the same API key (which we have done in the past).

My question is: How do we monitor the calls to this API in the Azure portal? I have turned on a number of diagnostics but none are appearing to give me the network info I need. Network Watcher appears to be for VMs. I want to be able to look at the calls that are logged using my key to troubleshoot this issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try application insights - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview
I need some more information about this case,
01. Are you calling Microsoft Translate API inside your application or you are developing an API using, Microsoft Translate API ?
02.Hope you are using azure web apps. Are you using slots to manage dev and test environment.
03. Are you using API Management ?

Comment: We are calling the API from inside our application. It appears the public IP we have set up for that box is failing when it hits authenticator. Connection is not accepted by the authentication service so doesn’t get as far as the translation service.